# how to add a variable to its current value, with consequent user input?

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic

I'm using a `switch` statement to store user inputted value. If a user chooses a certain case, they then ask for a number and that value is stored in a variable. What if the user chose the same case, how do you add that value to current value. 
I'm trying to store the first value in `activity_count` and then save the value to `activity_counts`. Then add `activity_counts` but the value keeps changing and keeps renewing with the loop. I know that my logic is wrong, can somebody give me a better idea of what i need to do?

Here's my code

```
for(daily_count = 0; daily_count < patient_count; daily_count++){
   int options;
   int activity_count;
   int activity_counts;

   cout << "1. Wash_Hands\n";
   cout << "9. Exit\n";

   cout << "\n";
   cout << "Choose a number with a description, which best decribes patient's obsessive activities: ";
   cin >> options;
   cout << "\n";


   switch(options){
       case 1:
           cout << "How much times did " << patient_name << " wash his hair:";
           cin >> activity_count;
           if(activity_count != 0)
                activity_counts = activity_count;
                activity_counts += activity_counts;
                cout << activity_counts << "\n\n";
                break;
       default:
            exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you put braces after the `if` until after `break`?

Comment: Your indentation doesn't correspond to real scope, use `{` and `}` to create block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more problems in your code:

```
       if (activity_count != 0)
            activity_counts = activity_count;
            activity_counts += activity_counts;
            cout << activity_counts << "\n\n";
            break;
```

Only the **first** statement after if is touched with the condition, others are performed always (probably missing braces `{` and `}` )

```
       if (activity_count != 0)
```

It seems to be **useless** - what is wrong with adding zero?

```
            activity_counts = activity_count;
```

This effectively **overwrites** `activity_counts` - is it what you mean?

```
            activity_counts += activity_counts;
```

It **doubles** `activity_counts` by adding the same value to it - is it what you mean?

> So, my friend, your code probably needs at least **these 2 changes**:

***Change 1***: **Inicialize** `activity_counts` with `0` and **move the declaration in front of `for` loop** - use

```
int activity_counts = 0;

for (daily_count = 0; daily_count < patient_count; daily_count++){
    int options;
    int activity_count;
```

*instead of this part of code* with an **uninitialized** declaration *(which produces a* **random value** *of the declared variable)* in the `for` loop:

```
for (daily_count = 0; daily_count < patient_count; daily_count++){
    int options;
    int activity_count;
    int activity_counts;
```

***Change 2***: *instedad of* lines

```
       if (activity_count != 0)
            activity_counts = activity_count;
            activity_counts += activity_counts;
```

use simply

```
            activity_counts += activity_count;
```

(note that there is **plural** on the left-hand side an **singular** on the right-hand one.)

Comment: thanks much.. but it still doesn't work.. i keep getting the same number i inputed on every input.. In my original code, i have the case in a function.. n the function i call in the case. would this affect the result?

Comment: Oh, it is my fault. The initialization declaration must be **before** the `for` loop - I just corrected it in my answer.